# open div on click of image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple module to develop. On click of an image I need to open up a div element that I have created.I have attached my HTML and javascript file.When I am loading the page the div wont be coming because I have given `style="display:none`

```js
myfunction() {
  document.getElementById('Chatbot').style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#Chatbot" id="chat" onclick="myfunction()">
    <img src="sticky.png" style="width:50px;height:50px">
  </a>

  <div id="Chatbot" style="display:none">

    <div id="header">
      Legal Genie
      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div><textarea rows="3" cols="20">Press enter to send your message</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Add `function` in front of `myfunction() {` to declare it. And change `visibility = "visible"` to `display = "block"` _(`visibility` and `display` are not the same thing)_. If that does not work, make sure your script is loaded before the HTML, or, even better, don't use `onclick=...` in your HTML, but `addEventListener` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vb3fnr2x/1/

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('Chatbot').style.display = "block";`

```js
function myfunction() {
  document.getElementById('Chatbot').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#Chatbot" id="chat" onclick="myfunction()">
    Some Image
  </a>

  <div id="Chatbot" style="display:none">

    <div id="header">
      Legal Genie
      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div><textarea rows="3" cols="20">Press enter to send your message</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using *inline scripts* and also avoid capitalising the first letter of your ID or class name.

Just add an event listener to your `#chat` anchor link that loads a function which sets the css `display` property of your div to `block` on click like this:

```js
/* JavaScript */
var chat = document.getElementById("chat");
var div = document.getElementById('chatbot');

function showDiv(){
 div.style.display = "block";
}

chat.addEventListener("click", showDiv);
```

```css
/* CSS */
a {text-decoration: none; padding: 5px; background-color: green; color: white;}
#chatbot {display: none;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<a type="button" href="#Chatbot" id="chat">Open Div</a>
<hr>
<div id="chatbot">
    <div id="header">
      Legal Genie
      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div><textarea rows="3" cols="20">Press enter to send your message</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be a simple way

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#chat').click( function(){
        if ( $('#Chatbot').hasClass('active') ) {
            $('#Chatbot').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#Chatbot').addClass('active');
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Add lil css

```
<style>
.active {
display:block!important;
}
</style>
```

Your HTML

```
<body>


<div id="chat">
    Some Image
</div>
<div id="Chatbot"  style="display:none">

    <div id="header">
        Legal Genie
        <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div><textarea rows="3" cols="20">Press enter to send your message</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```